# If $\psi \in \mathcal{l}^2$,then $\{\alpha\in A: \psi(\alpha)\neq0\}$ is at most countable. Prove.

Tags: real-analysis

Here, $\mathcal{l}^2$ denotes $L^2$ where the measure is the counting measure.
It is in Rudin's Real and Complex analysis p.84, where he explains,

> For is $A_n$ is the set of all $\alpha$ where $|\psi(\alpha)|>1/n$, then the number of elements of $A$ is at most $\sum_{\alpha\in A_n}|n\psi(\alpha)|^2$ .

But I have no clue why this statement holds.
Would you give me any hint or comment?
Thank you.

Comment: What is $\alpha$, what is $\psi$, and what is $A$? If you pose a question, be sure that it can be understood. Thanks.

Comment: The definitions are a bit spread all over the post and the title, but it seems you are picking the measure space $(A,\mathcal P(A),\mu)$, where $A$ is a set and $\mu$ is the counting measure, and you are considering $\psi\in \ell^2(A)$.

Comment: What is "the" counting measure on a set? Maybe "a" counting measure with countable support?

Comment: I see now in both english and french translation of Rudin Book, and in french translation the write :  "then the number of elements of $A_n$ is at most ...."

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp the counting measure is [the counting measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_measure).

Comment: @Hamza: That is what I thought anyway since the sum is finite.

Comment: @Hamza: Alright, thanks.

Comment: Thank you, all. I noticed my question was not as organized as it should be, but you filled in the gaps. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A_n := \{a : |\psi(a)| > 1/n\}$. Assume that $A_n$ is not finite. Then there exists an infinite countable set $A_n'\subset A_n$ for which we have
$$
\int_{A_n'}|\psi|^2\,d\mu > \frac 1 {n^2}\int_{A_n'}\,d\mu = \frac 1 {n^2}\mu(A_n') = \infty.
$$
But $\psi\in L^2(A,\mu)$. A contradiction. Therefore, $A_n$ must be finite and thus
$$
\{a : \psi(a)\neq 0\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n
$$
is countable.